# PHP/Jquery -> Plugin: DataTables, how to use the formatter in an array?

Tags: php, jquery, plugins, datatables, formatter

I use the (server-side processing) pipelining data feature from [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to reduce Ajax calls for paging.

```
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'order_number', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'customer',  'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'commission',   'dt' =>  2 ),
array(
    'db'        => 'timestamp_created',
    'dt'        => '3',
    'formatter' => ???
)
```

);

My question is how can i configure the formatter? For example i have a timestamp so i want to format this timestamp from my database into a more user-friendly-format. This isn´t a problem, but i can not write a normal php function - which would do this for me. If i do it, i get an error. So can anyone help me out and is able to give me a example in how to use this formatter?

## Edited:

The answer is not that i didn´t get it by myself in a correct way, the answer is my php version was too old and so the formatter didn´t worked as it should be working.
You need at least PHP version 5.3!

Maybe this will help somebody in the future.

Comment: There's a pretty good example in their documentation (https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) on the Server-side script tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'order_number', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'customer',  'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'commission',   'dt' =>  2 ),
array(
    'db'        => 'timestamp_created',
    'dt'        => '3',
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                    return date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime($d));
                }
)
);
```